# How to select 2 cross split string column in single query

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

```
CREATE TABLE #StudentClasses
(
    ID INT, 
    Student VARCHAR(100), 
    Classes VARCHAR(100),
    CCode VARCHAR(30)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #StudentClasses
     SELECT 1, 'Mark', 'Maths,Science,English', 'US,UK,AUS' 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, 'John', 'Science,English', 'BE,DE'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, 'Robert', 'Maths,English', 'CA,IN'
     GO

SELECT *
FROM #StudentClasses
GO

SELECT ID, Student, value ,value
FROM #StudentClasses 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Classes, ',') 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CCode, ',')
```

Comment: Is it too late to change your table design and store your lists in a separate table rather than a comma separated values in a varchar column? If not you should definitely do this, dealing with comma separated lists will cause you headache after headache, bit the bullet and store it them in a new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be put in the very first place: Do not store delimited data! If there is any chance to change your table's design, you should use related side-tables to store data this kind...

Your question is not much better than the one before. Without your **expected result** any suggestion must be guessing.

What I guess: You want to transform `'Maths,Science,English', 'US,UK,AUS'` in a way, that Maths goes along with US, Science along with UK and English matches AUS. Try this

```
SELECT sc.ID
      ,sc.Student
      ,A.[key] AS Position 
      ,A.[value] AS Class
      ,B.[value] AS CCode
FROM #StudentClasses sc
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(Classes,',','","') + '"]') A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(CCode,',','","') + '"]') B
WHERE A.[key]=B.[key];
```

You did not tell us your SQL Server's version... But you tagged with Azure. Therefore I assume, that v2016 is okay for you. With a lower version (or a lower compatibility level of the given database) there is no JSON support.

Why JSON at all? This is the best way at the moment to split CSV data and get the fragments together with their position within the array. Regrettfully `STRING_SPLIT()` does not guarantee to return the expected order. With versions lower than v2016 there are several more or less ugly tricks...

If you need your result *side-by-side* you should read about *conditional aggregation*.

Comment: If i just want to store Integer value in column how do i convert it's showing can not convert to Int.                                                                                                                       ==>Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '48,49,50,51' to data type int

Comment: @GauravGangwar your question does not show such a list... Please do not add to a question but start a new one. And please don't forget to state your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

use select all or use alias

```
CREATE TABLE #StudentClasses
 (ID INT, Student VARCHAR(100), Classes VARCHAR(100),CCode varchar(30))

 INSERT INTO #StudentClasses
 SELECT 1, 'Mark', 'Maths,Science,English', 'US,UK,AUS' 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 'John', 'Science,English', 'BE,DE'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'Robert', 'Maths,English', 'CA,IN'


SELECT *,v1.value as clases,v2.value as codes
FROM #StudentClasses 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Classes, ',') v2
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CCode, 
',') v1
```

Comment: Solution is good but this is not my requirement you can check in above answer is my solution. Many thanks for you response.